# Bearer token not getting included in SwaggerUI

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-ui, aspnetboilerplate

I am using **AspNet Boilerplate** framework. I am trying to implement authentication through **AzureAD** in my application. I am using **ASP.NET core 3.0** and testing my application through swagger. I am seeing the token is not getting included in the header.

ConfigureServices() method of Startup.cs

```
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
                    {
                        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                        {
                            TokenUrl = new Uri(My Token Url),
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(My Authorization Url),
                            Scopes = { { "api://357...../user_impersonation", "Access adt-service" } }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Configure() method of Startup.cs:

```
            {                
                options.OAuthClientId("22............");
                options.OAuthScopeSeparator(" ");
                
            });
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you receiving the token in the first place, when you authenticate? In my answer, I'll assume you are.

You do not show that entirely in your snippet, but you must be doing something like below to configure Swagger services, right?

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc(...);

    options.AddSecurityDefinition(
        "oauth",
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
            {
                Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                {
                    TokenUrl = new Uri(My Token Url),
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(My Authorization Url),
                    Scopes = { { "api://357...../user_impersonation", "Access adt-service" } }
                }
            }
    });
});
```

If you are, simply add a security requirement to your options, and the token shall already be included in your requests:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc(...);

    options.AddSecurityDefinition(
        "oauth",
        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
            Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows()
            {
                Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow()
                {
                    TokenUrl = new Uri(My Token Url),
                    AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(My Authorization Url),
                    Scopes = { { "api://357...../user_impersonation", "Access adt-service" } }
                }
            }
    });

    options.AddSecurityRequirement(
        new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id = "oauth"
                }
            },
            oauthScopes.Keys.ToArray() // array with scopes' keys used above in the security definition
        }
    });
});
```

Please, note the addition of `options.AddSecurityRequirement`. The name/id `"oauth"` is just an identifying name to the security definition.

These snippets work for .net 5. I believe they may do so for .net core 3

Comment: This line was the key! oauthScopes.Keys.ToArray() // array with scopes' keys used above in the security definition. I have seen so many examples and this is the first time I've ever seen any attention shown to that line, beside new List<string>(). THANK YOU. It still doesn't close the lock icon, but the id_token I'm getting back actually belongs to the user and not just the client.